# selected wrong firebase database after firebase init how to switch in original database

Tags: firebase

I am using vscode for my project.
When deployed project to the firebase, accidentally I selected wrong database after "firebase init" command so my environment firebase object initialized to bigbangshopping firebase but I accidentally selected bigshopping database for hosting.
Now how to switch bigbangshopping I have no idea.Would you please help me to have the solution

Answer (score 4):

Just use the command
`firebase use <project_id>`
And it will be switched